# 'DataFrame constructor not properly called' in dict comprehension with for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Edited question to better present the issue.

I'm learning data analysis and can't figure out what's the problem here.

I get data through API and make a df out of it where rows represent one match each and one of the columns has all kinds of information about all players in a dota match in the form of list of nested dicts (the original dict is kinda huge so I don't know how to include it here if it's even needed).

What I want to do is to create one df with detailed stats for particular player for every game. To do that I'm trying:

1. to loop through every row (each representing a game) in column 'players' in original df
2. create dfs for every one of them and store them in a dict (now we have a dict of dfs each consisting of 10 rows for 10 players in a game with columns representing their stats)
3. loop through these stored dfs to find in them needed row (by player_id) and append it to the final df.

Now comes the problem:

So

```
pd.DataFrame(in_df.players[1])
```

does work in itself and creates a df.

```
{i: pd.DataFrame(in_df.players[i]) for i in range(10)}
```

also works as intended.
But this one:

```
names_for_dfs = [i for i in range(len(in_df))]
{name: pd.DataFrame(in_df.players[name]) for name in names_for_dfs}
```

doesn't work. Function in question:

```
def get_player_stats(in_df, cols_to_keep, player_id):
#create a df from 'players' column for each game (row) - it contains 10 rows for 10 players
#find a row with player_id for player in each game (each df) and append it to out_df
out_df = pd.DataFrame()

names_for_dfs = [row for row in range(len(in_df))]
     
dfs = {
name : pd.DataFrame(in_df.loc[name, 'players'])
for name in names_for_dfs
} 

for name, df in dfs.items():
    out_df = out_df.append(df[df.account_id.isin([player_id])], ignore_index=True)  # get a row by id and append to final df
return out_df[cols_to_keep]
```

I get an error:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-27-1a40ba2737e6> in <module>
      7     return dfs
      8 
----> 9 dfs = get_player_stats(matches_data, core_stats, 34505203)
     10 dfs

<ipython-input-27-1a40ba2737e6> in get_player_stats(in_df, cols_to_keep, player_id)
      3     dfs = {
      4     name : pd.DataFrame(in_df.loc[name, 'players'])
----> 5     for name in names_for_dfs
      6     }
      7     return dfs

<ipython-input-27-1a40ba2737e6> in <dictcomp>(.0)
      3     dfs = {
      4     name : pd.DataFrame(in_df.loc[name, 'players'])
----> 5     for name in names_for_dfs
      6     }
      7     return dfs

~\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __init__(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
    507                 )
    508             else:
--> 509                 raise ValueError("DataFrame constructor not properly called!")
    510 
    511         NDFrame.__init__(self, mgr, fastpath=True)

ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

So I began to create a test data to present to you for reproducing. I called for sample of original df and .to_dict() it to better see how it's constructed. I came up with this sample data based on that:

```
data = {'match_id': {0: 5490791923.0, 1: 5490651026.0, 2: 5490555360.0},
 'players': {0: [{'match_id': 5490791923, 'stat1': 101, 'stat2': [1, 2, 3], 'stat3': {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: [1, 2, 3]}}],
             1: [{'match_id': 5490791923, 'stat1': 101, 'stat2': [1, 2, 3], 'stat3': {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: [1, 2, 3]}}],
             2: [{'match_id': 5490791923, 'stat1': 101, 'stat2': [1, 2, 3], 'stat3': {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: [1, 2, 3]}}]
            }
       }
```

So then I created df from that and it kinda looks like original.

```
stats = pd.DataFrame(data = data)
```

I then used the same steps as above to make sure that everything is ok but things went smooth and without error.

```
in_df = stats
names_for_dfs = [i for i in range(len(in_df))]
dfs = {name: pd.DataFrame(in_df.loc[name, 'players']) for name in names_for_dfs}
```

prints out this

```
{0:      match_id  stat1      stat2                       stat3
 0  5490791923    101  [1, 2, 3]  {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: [1, 2, 3]},
 1:      match_id  stat1      stat2                       stat3
 0  5490791923    101  [1, 2, 3]  {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: [1, 2, 3]},
 2:      match_id  stat1      stat2                       stat3
 0  5490791923    101  [1, 2, 3]  {1: 1, 2: 2, 3: [1, 2, 3]}}
```

So now I start to think what can be the difference that prevents the solution from working originally?
Code with which I got the original data:

```
def get_player_ids(team_id: int):
    players = requests.get(f'https://api.opendota.com/api/teams/{team_id}/players').json()
    ids = []
    keys = ['account_id', 'name']
    for player in players:
        for k, v in player.items():
            if k in keys:
                ids.append({k: v})
    print(ids)
    return ids

def get_team_id(team_name: str):
    teams = pd.DataFrame(requests.get('https://api.opendota.com/api/teams').json())
    team_id = int(teams.team_id[teams.name.str.lower() == team_name.lower()])
    get_player_ids(team_id)
    return team_id

columns = ['match_id', 'duration', 'radiant_score', 'dire_score', 'radiant_gold_adv',
           'radiant_xp_adv', 'radiant_team', 'dire_team', 'players', 'league', 'patch', 'start_time']
def get_match_data_for_team(team_id: int):    
    l = requests.get(f'https://api.opendota.com/api/teams/{team_id}/matches').json()
    match_ids = [d['match_id'] for d in l]
    matches_data = []
    for m_id in match_ids:
        matches_data.append(requests.get('http://api.opendota.com/api/matches/' + f'{m_id}').json())
    
    return pd.DataFrame(matches_data)[columns]

matches_data = get_match_data_for_team(get_team_id('nigma'))
```

EDIT:
Fixed, following code now works:

```
def get_player_stats(in_df, cols_to_keep, player_id):
    #create a df from 'players' column for each game (row) - it contains 10 rows for 10 players
    #find a row with player_id for MC in each game (df) and append it to out_df
    out_df = pd.DataFrame()
    dfs = {}

    names_for_dfs = [row for row in range(len(in_df))]
    for name in names_for_dfs:
        for player_dict in in_df.players[name]:
            if isinstance(player_dict, dict) and player_dict['account_id'] == player_id:
                df = pd.DataFrame({key: [value] for key, value in player_dict.items()})
                dfs.update({name: df})

    for name, df in dfs.items():
        out_df = out_df.append(df)
        
    return out_df[cols_to_keep]
```

But I miss some rows

```
if isinstance(player_dict, dict) and player_dict['account_id'] == player_id:
```

with that condition it seems, because `matches_data` has 193 rows, but `out_df` only 143.
And this way

```
out_df = pd.DataFrame()
dfs = {}
for match_number in range(len(matches_data)):
    for player_dict in matches_data.players[match_number]:
        if isinstance(player_dict, dict):
            df = pd.DataFrame({key: [value] for key, value in player_dict.items()})
            dfs.update({match_number: df})
for name, df in dfs.items():
    out_df = out_df.append(df[df.account_id.isin([34505203])], ignore_index=True)
```

I get even less - 138 rows. How do I search correctly for needed player in these nests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. There are two issues:

1. Pandas is raising an error when it tries to make a `DataFrame` out of each player's `dict` (one of the ten in a `list` per match `index` stored in the 'players' column `Series`) because all player `dicts` have values of varying array lengths. For example, the 'match_id' value is just one number, but the 'ability_upgrades_arr' value is a list of many numbers. This is easily fixed by putting the value in a list, essentially making each value's array length equal to 1.
2. When you iterate over the matches looking for player `dicts`, sometimes they aren't there (check the data). So Pandas is trying to make a `DataFrame` out of a `str` or a `float` (`np.nan`). Fix this with the built-in Python function `isinstance()`.

Here's my version of your code, which just gets the `dict` of each player `dict` as a `DataFrame` as the value to an arbitrary key, as you attempted above. From here, just dive into the `dict` through iteration and find data on one player name.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd


def get_team_matches_from_api(team: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    "Get data from all matches played by :arg:`team`"
    
    # First, pull all teams from OpenDOTA so that we can...
    teams = pd.DataFrame(requests.get('https://api.opendota.com/api/teams').json())

    # ...get Team ID of :arg:`team`
    team_id = int(teams.team_id[teams.name.str.lower() == team.lower()])

    # Second, pull all games played by :arg:`team` so that we can...
    team_matches = requests.get(f'https://api.opendota.com/api/teams/{team_id}/matches').json()

    # ...get match IDs for each match played
    match_ids = [team_match['match_id'] for team_match in team_matches]

    # Third, go back to OpenDOTA and pull each match played by :arg:`team` using our match IDs above
    matches_data = []
    for match_id in match_ids:
        matches_data.append(requests.get(f'http://api.opendota.com/api/matches/{match_id}').json())

    # Fourth, put the data from the pulled matches into a `DataFrame`
    columns = ['match_id', 'duration', 'radiant_score', 'dire_score', 'radiant_gold_adv', 'radiant_xp_adv', 'radiant_team', 'dire_team', 'players', 'league', 'patch', 'start_time']
    df = pd.DataFrame(matches_data)[columns]

    return df.fillna('N/A')


def get_player_data_from_team_matches(team_matches: pd.DataFrame) -> dict:
    "Pull player data from all games in :arg:`team_matches`"
    
    players_from_team_matches = dict()

    for match_number in range(team_matches.players.shape[0]):

        for player_dict in team_matches.players[match_number]:
            if isinstance(player_dict, dict):
                df = pd.DataFrame({key: [value] for key, value in player_dict.items()})
                players_from_team_matches.update({match_number: df})

    return players_from_team_matches


# DataFrame of all Nigma matches
nigma = get_team_matches_from_api('nigma')

# Dictionary of all player data from every Nigma match
nigma_players = get_player_data_from_team_matches(nigma)
```

Comment: Managed to get out_df thanks to you! Added last edit to the question - somehow we lose rows in the process

Answer (score 1):

I would try:

- Simplifying your function to something like I have below, which meets your goal of making a `DataFrame` of a given player's compiled stats across all matches.
- Dictionary logic helps to alleviate some indexing complexities when extracting data from nested `dicts` within a `DataFrame`, so this function takes a `DataFrame` as `in_df` but changes it to a `dict` with the `DataFrame.to_dict()` method.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

def get_player_stats(in_df, player_id):
    
    df = pd.DataFrame()

    for match, players in in_df.to_dict()['players'].items():
        # {match1: {players}}

        for player, info in players.items():
            # {player1: {info}}

            if info['account_id'] == player_id:
                # {player1: {'account_id': player_id}}

                df = df.append(pd.Series(data=info, name=match))

    cols_to_keep = [col for col in df.columns if col != 'account_id']

    return df[cols_to_keep]

# I assume your data looks something like this:
matches_2020 = {

    'date': {
        'match1': '2020-06-01',
        'match2': '2020-06-02'
    },
    'players': {
        'match1': {
            'player1': {'account_id': 'FAKER', 'cs': 700, 'champ': 'Zoe'},
            'player2': {'account_id': 'BJERGSON', 'cs': 500, 'champ': 'Talon'}
        },
        'match2': {
            'player1': {'account_id': 'FAKER', 'cs': 800, 'champ': 'Syndra'},
            'player2': {'account_id': 'REDMERCY', 'cs': 500, 'champ': 'Zed'}
        }
    }
}

in_df = pd.DataFrame(matches_2020)

# Let's pull Faker's stats:
faker = get_player_stats(in_df, 'FAKER')
print(faker)
```

Output:

```
         champ     cs
match1     Zoe  700.0
match2  Syndra  800.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your input! I should prob add how data looks like. But do u have any idea why my approach isn't working tho?

Comment: Hmm, my best guess is that the pandas are sad about how you used the `.loc[]` method on `in_df`. You got the `ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!` exception within your `dict` comprehension. I would look at the [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html#pandas.DataFrame.loc) and see if you can rephrase the `DataFrame` construction. For reference, I was able to use the code I gave above to use `DataFrame` construction `dict` comp successfully like so: `dfs = {i: pd.DataFrame(faker.loc['match1']) for i in range(5)}`.

Comment: actually I just returned to this today and it works. I mean without any changes. I should also mention that it worked previously at some point, also in the exact same form. So I have absolutely no idea what happened

Comment: Actually things don't work so I edited the question with more details and steps to reproduce